# HTML Get two divs to align side by side and not wrap when the browser is resized

Tags: css, html, styles, positioning

I am using the below code and getting a problem where if I resize the browser my mainpage div wraps below the menubar div, I have tried min and max width and nothing has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want the mainpage div to not drop below the menubar and stay side by side with it even if the browser is made smaller.

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar" style="width: 16%; height: 100px;" title="menu" align = "center"> <!-- This is the code for the menubar, to add a new option to the menubar-->
                                                                                    <!-- Add a new <li> tag below the bottom link, to delete a link, delete the desired
                                                                                    link element. -->
    <ul>
        <li style="align: center;"><img alt="logo" height="63" src="images/ClevelandLogo.gif" width="126" /></li>
        <li ><a href="index.html" style="height: 20px;" class="auto-style5">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthyth.html">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="rhtrhrthrth">Site map</a></li>
        <li><a href="thrrthrthtr">Rules & Procdures</a></li>
        <li><a href="rth" style="height: 20px">Envirommental</a></li>
        <li><a href="rth">Energy</a></li>
        <li><a href="rhtrhrth">IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthtrhrt">SAP</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthtrhtrhtrhtrh.html" style="height: 20px; width: 180px;">rhtrhtrh</a></li>
        <li><a href="quality.html">Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="hr.html">Human resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="eng.html">Engineering</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="tees.html">wrefwefwefwef</a></li>
        <li><a href="cmp.html">Company mobile phones</a></li>
        <li><a href="cms.html">Climate Survery Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.html">Sports Dome</a></li>



    </ul>
</div>
<!--The mainpage div is where all the page's indivdual content is displayed.-->

<div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 486px;  float:left; color: #000000; font-size: 11pt;"> 
<p> -0je45iwgtjj4eg0prjegtgfjotrsjgse'[agpraeogjk-odetkgbokporgkspfkdgkpfdgkpdfkg</p>
</div>
<!-- The container1 div is used to create the bottom green line in the site -->
```

CSS:

```
#mainpage 
{
    border: thin solid #008852;
    width: 84%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    color: #008852;
}

#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited 
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menubar ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#menubar a:link, #menubar a:visited
{

    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EFF1EB;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px;
    position: fixed;

}
```

Comment: I cannot access it at work

Comment: @Rob: I have formatted the CSS codes in your question. During that I found an extra line break before the `ul` in `#menubar ul` and have removed it. Please roll back the change if it is not what you meant it to be.

Comment: I have also fixed a few HTML errors which probably weren't helping matters. I 've setup a jsfiddle but I'm struggling to see what the issue is: http://jsfiddle.net/3hGTc/

Comment: if you resize the page and make it narrower the mainpage (grey box) wraps underneath the menubar to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both of your div's in another element with a fixed width. Then float the menu bar and the main page to the left.

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
section {
    width:110px;
}
```

Something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/uBgg3/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to build can be done as follows.

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div class="logo"><img alt="logo" src="http://placehold.it/126x63" /></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthyth.html">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="rhtrhrthrth">Site map</a></li>
        <li><a href="thrrthrthtr">Rules & Procdures</a></li>
        <li><a href="rth">Envirommental</a></li>
        <li><a href="rth">Energy</a></li>
        <li><a href="rhtrhrth">IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthtrhrt">SAP</a></li>
        <li><a href="rthtrhtrhtrhtrh.html">rhtrhtrh</a></li>
        <li><a href="quality.html">Quality</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="hr.html">Human resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="prod.html">Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="eng.html">Engineering</a></li>
        <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="tees.html">wrefwefwefwef</a></li>
        <li><a href="cmp.html">Company mobile phones</a></li>
        <li><a href="cms.html">Climate Survery Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="sports.html">Sports Dome</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainpage">
    <p>Some sample text...</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#menubar {
    width: auto; 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#mainpage {
    overflow: auto;
    border: thin solid #008852;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #008852;
}
#mainpage a:link, #mainpage a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#menubar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menubar a:link, #menubar a:visited {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #EFF1EB;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px;
}
```

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sXNLT/

I cleaned up the inline styles since they were getting in the way.  Use CSS rules, so much easier to maintain.

Float your `#menubar` to the left and set `height:auto` so that you can see all the links without any overflow issues.

On `#mainpage`, no need to float and set `overflow: auto` to prevent the  content from wrapping around the floated menu.

Finally, no need for `position: fixed` in your navigation links.

Answer (score -1):

You could put the two divs in a html table (2 columns, 1 row) and set the width of your body column to a specific value or percentage.